# Is TextView's setShadowLayer supported on all APIs?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, layer, shadow

On the Android developer website (below) there is a list of supported and unsupported operations, setShadowLayer is listed with an "X" (other than text). Does this mean it can be disabled by the user or that it isn't supported on all API levels?

I'm doing custom drawing that depends on setShadowLayer and am trying to determine what effect it could have on my user base. Could it cause slow-downs with drawing or render incorrectly?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method was added in API level 1

see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: does hardware acceleration depend on or affect this in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Check Android `API` here,http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer(float, float, float, int), thess `java` `method` and `xml` `attribute` are added in `API 1`, so it means it can be used in almost any API levels.